# Java: upload file to FTP problem (packets lost)

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to transfer a file from my Java application to an FTP server
the program works, the file is transferred, but when I go to open in the FTO folder, the file is corrupted, I think that packets are lost during the file transfer.  Why?  And how can I fix this?

Another question, how can I stop the `while` if I want to stop the file upload?

Thanks everybody!

The code inside my class:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
InputStream is = null;
//...
try{
 client.connect(MY_FTP_URL);
 client.login(USER, PASS);
 InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file_path);
 OutputStream os = client.storeFileStream(file_name);
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 int len;
 //I use this way to check the transfer progress
 while((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1){
  os.write(buffer, 0, len);
  os.flush();
 }
 os.close();
} catch (IOException e){
 e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
 try{
  if(is != null){
   is.close();
  }
  client.disconnect();
 } catch(IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Comment: (1) don't write this yourself, use a library (2) don't use FTP unless you absolutely have to, use [SCP via JSch](http://seancode.blogspot.com/2008/02/jsch-scp-file-in-java.html) instead.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, but it's almost certainly not "packet loss" - FTP is layered on top of TCP, which provides a reliable byte stream.

Comment: yes it's really strange but the output file contains less characters or lines.. (and it isn't trimmed)

Comment: What OS are you using?  And what OS is the server running?  This could be an issue with binary file transfer.

Comment: If you really suspect the network layer, you can use Wireshark to capture the data that you're sending over the network. But it's a good general rule to always presume that it's your own code that's at fault unless you have a very good reason to think otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Net/FrequentlyAskedQuestions):

> Q: Why are my files corrupt after
>   transfer?
>
> A: The most common cause for this is
>   when the file is transfered as ASCII
>   but the contents of the file are not
>   ASCII and the file should be
>   transferred as BINARY. RFC 959 says
>   the default transfer mode should be
>   ASCII. FTPClient conforms to the
>   standard. You must explicitly call
>   setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); to
>   request binary transfer mode after
>   logging in to the FTP server.

Call `setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);`

Answer (score 2):

FTP has two modes ASCII (typically the default) and binary. If you are transferring anything other then text you must set the client into binary mode.

How to set the mode varies on the FTP client implementation, but for Commons IO see
http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileType(int)